# 2 x 2 Phase Portrait for 2 x 2 Linear System with Real Coefficients. Boyce, p395, Figure 7.5.4a

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-explanation

[image]

> The given general solution for some linear system is
>   $
> x= c_{2} \mathbf{ x^{(1)} }(t) + c_{2} \mathbf{ x^{(2)} }(t) = 
> c_{1}\ 
> \left(\begin{array}{l}
> 1\\
> \sqrt{2}
> \end{array}\right)\ 
> e^{-t}+
> c_{2}
> \left(\begin{array}{l}
> -\sqrt{2}\\
> 1
> \end{array}\right)\
> e^{-4t} \qquad (21)
> $.
>
> Graphs of the solution (21) for several values of $c_{1}$ and $c_{2}$ are shown in Figure 7. $5.4a$.
>   The solution $x^{(1)}(t)$ approaches the origin along the line $x_{2}=\sqrt{2}x_{1}$, and the solution $x^{(2)}(t)$ approaches the origin along the line $x_{1}=-\sqrt{2}x_{2}$....

**(1)** Please explain this last sentence? I know $\color{brown}{ x_2 = \sqrt{2}x_{1} \iff } 
\begin{bmatrix}
x_1\\
x_2
\end{bmatrix}
= x_1 \begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
\sqrt{2}
\end{bmatrix}$
and 
$ \color{green} { x_{1}=-\sqrt{2}x_{2} } \iff 
 \begin{bmatrix}
x_1\\
x_2
\end{bmatrix}
= x_2 \begin{bmatrix}
-\sqrt{2} \\
1
\end{bmatrix}$

> As $ t\rightarrow\infty$, the solution $x^{(2)}(t)$ is negligible compared to $x^{(1)}(t)$ .

**(2)** Why 'negligible'? I know when $k > 0$, $\lim_{t \to \infty} e^{-kt} = 0 $

> Thus, unless $c_{1}=0$, the solution (21) approaches the origin tangent to the line $x_{2}=\sqrt{2}x_{1}$.

**(3)** Please explain this last sentence? I know if $c_1 =0 $ then any solution must be
$ c_{2} \mathbf{ x^{(2)} }(t)$

> ... If the eigenvalues were positive rather than negative, then the trajectories would be similar but traversed in the outward direction.

**(4)**  Please explain this last sentence?

Comment: Is there a "$=$" missing in the first equation between $\mathbf{x}^{(2)}(t)$ and $c_1$?

Comment: @Roland Thanks. yes. fixed it. any other errors?

Comment: As pointed out in my answer, the black arrows which have $\mathbf{x}^{(1)}$ and $\mathbf{x}^{(2)}$ as a label might be pointing at the wrong spot. Does my answer provide some help to you, by the way?

Answer (score 0):

The first equation tells us (implicitly) $$\mathbf{x}^{(1)}(t)= \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ \sqrt{2}\end{pmatrix}e^{-t}, \quad \mathbf{x}^{(2)}(t)= \begin{pmatrix} -\sqrt{2}\\ 1\end{pmatrix}e^{-4t}.$$

1. This means that, starting with $t=0$ and using $e^0 = 1$, we have initial values

   $$\mathbf{x}^{(1)}(0)= \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ \sqrt{2}\end{pmatrix}, \quad \mathbf{x}^{(2)}(0)= \begin{pmatrix} -\sqrt{2}\\ 1\end{pmatrix}.$$

   As $t$ increases from $0$ towards $\infty$, the factors $e^{-k}$ and $e^{-4k}$ decrease from $1$ to $0$, i.e. the solutions $\mathbf{x}^{(1)}(t)$ and $\mathbf{x}^{(2)}(t)$ run along the red/green line. In view of this, the black arrows are misleadingly positioned.
2. This argument of Boyce is a bit handwavy here, and my explanation is going to be similarly handwavy - I hope that this makes it more understandable. The idea is that $e^{-4t}$ converges faster to $0$ than $e^{-t}$ does. I would not call it negligible, but the two solutions converge to zero at different rates. One way to see this is to write $c_1 \mathbf{x}^{(1)}(t)+ c_2 \mathbf{x}^{(2)}(t)$ as

   $$e^{-t}\left(c_1\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ \sqrt{2}\end{pmatrix} + c_2\begin{pmatrix} -\sqrt{2}\\ 1\end{pmatrix}e^{-3t}\right) .$$

   As $t$ increases, the second summand in the brackets goes to $0$, while the first one remains.
3. Because of this difference in convergence speed, a linear combination of the two solutions gets very close to $\mathbf{x}^{(1)}(t)$, as the part with $\mathbf{x}^{(2)}(t)$ 'converges away'. You can see this behavior in the blue arrows, which are the general solutions of the system. All of them approach the origin along the direction of $\pm \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ \sqrt{2}\end{pmatrix}$ eventually - the part of $\mathbf{x}^{(2)}(t)$ dimishes away. I am aware that this explanation is similarly handwavy as the original one.
4. This is lacking context. How are the solutions related to eigenvalues (of which matrix)?